# Validate Date format using C# 4.0

Tags: c#, validation, date

In our existing website code I encountered the following piece of code:

```
private static bool IsDate(string inputText)
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime.Parse(inputText);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Can this piece of code be optimized by using .NET 4.0 framework feature?

Comment: Could be better in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. But it could be optimized using other Framework features that have been around for a lot longer than 4.0:

```
private static bool IsDate(string inputText)
{
    DateTime d;
    return DateTime.TryParse(inputText, out d);
}
```

Comment: If we need to consider culture infomation like: mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy. How can we make sure the data format is consistence?

Comment: Call the overload that takes a FormatProvider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx

Comment: You are right. I will wait to see if anyone can give me some other opinions for C# 4.0 feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool IsDate(string Input)
    {
        DateTime RV;
        return DateTime.TryParse(Input, out RV);
    }
```